# devcon disable device not found win 10

Tags: keyboard, driver, devcon

I've recently spilled some coffee on my laptop (Asus ROG G55VW) and it messed my keyboard up. i now connected a usb keyboard and use it instead. The problem is that my normal keyboard sometimes interferes with my new one for no reason (since it is filled with coffee i suppose). i tried uninstalling the keyboard driver with no success (windows re-installs on start-up even after disabling automatic driver install) and i also tried installing a different driver for my keyboard that would make it not work, but it seems windows isn't very happy with that and tries to repair on startup unsuccessfully and forces me to restore my windows from a backup restore.

i am now trying to use devcon to solve the problem but it seems to be unable to uninstall the driver aswell.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" find *PNP030B
ACPI\ATK3001\4&2FDE785C&0                                   : PC/AT Enhanced PS/2 Keyboard (101/102-Key)
1 matching device(s) found.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" disable *PNP030B
ACPI\ATK3001\4&2FDE785C&0                                   : Disable failed
No matching devices found.

would love some help regarding the reason for failing to disable.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are appropriate to ask here.

Comment: This is not a question about programming. please read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: oh sorry. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are in the wrong place, as others have said.
2. You are either running this not as administrator or you are running the wrong version (32bit vs 64bit versions)